# What's the name of Widget

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I have this widget that I'm trying to duplicate ( the exterior widget or container). I see that this widget is common between a lot of GUI interfaces(i.e the frame with the title). My question is is there a predefined widget in Tkinter that reassemble this one or should I code it from scratch.

For more clearance, The widget I'm talking about is the border with heading (called configure Diagnostics in the image)

[image]

Comment: I think `ttk.LabelFrame` is the closest to what you are looking for. If `LabelFrame` doesn't work for you, you can always make something like this using a label for the title setting its background and a frame for the widgets bellow.

Comment: ttk.LabelFrame set the boarder but can doesn't put the title in a boarder which I want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the closest result using `ttk.LabelFrame` with proper style:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('default')

# labeloutside=True will put the text outside the frame
# labelmargins=0 will remove the paddings at the left and right sides of the text
s.configure("TLabelframe", labeloutside=True, labelmargins=0, relief="raised")

# using a Label widget for the text and set its width big enough to fill the horizontal space
frame = ttk.LabelFrame(root, width=600, height=400,
                       labelwidget=tk.Label(root, text="Configure Diagnostics over IP/HSFZ", anchor="w", bd=2, relief="raised", width=100))
frame.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]